# How to add from model data string of HTML to Razor

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor

Hi i have model with property content. model.Content is HTML tags like object string

when i try

```
@foreach (var user in @Model.Organizations){
     @user.Content
}
```

he is don`t create html tags just print text. how i can create tags from text?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmVDh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `@Html.Raw()`

```
 @Html.Raw(user.Content)
```